# Is there an alternative method to retrieve the string data in the code below?

Tags: c, data-structures

In the code below the user is asked to input various details about a newborn child.For some reason the program skips over the prompt to enter the parents' names.I have tried using the scanf,gets and fgets functions but none of them work.Is there any a way to modify the code to allow this input to be made?

Here is the code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{

    char name[50];
    float weight;
    int year;
    char parent_names[50];

}newborn;


int main()
{
    
    int i;
    newborn child[2];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("\nWhat is the child's name?\n");
        fgets(child[i].name,50,stdin);
        
        
        printf("What is the child's weight in Kg?\n");
        scanf("%f",&child[i].weight);
        
        
        printf("What is the child's year of birth?\n");
        scanf("%d",&child[i].year);
        
        
        printf("What are the names of the Mother and Father?\n");
        fgets(child[i].parent_names,50,stdin);  

        printf("Name:%s\n",child[i].name);
        printf("Weight:%f\n",child[i].weight);
        printf("Year of Birth:%d\n",child[i].year);
        printf("Parent names:%s\n",child[i].parent_names);
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this `scanf("%d",&child[i].year);` captures the int but leaves the `\n` as the next character to be read from `stdin`. `fgets` reads stream to the `\n`, so the call to `fgets` captures that `\n` and continues. It's doing everything properly, except that you forgot about the `\n` on the stdin stream. To fix that create a string and capture the input for weight and year as strings and convert them to `float` and `int` using `atof` and `atoi` from `stdlib.h`, like this:

```
int i;
char buf[10];
newborn child[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    printf("\nWhat is the child's name?\n");
    fgets(child[i].name,50,stdin);
    
    
    printf("What is the child's weight in Kg?\n");
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
    child[i].weight = atof(buf);
    
    
    printf("What is the child's year of birth?\n");
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
    child[i].year = atoi(buf);
    
    
    printf("What are the names of the Mother and Father?\n");
    fgets(child[i].parent_names,50,stdin);  

    printf("Name:%s\n",child[i].name);
    printf("Weight:%f\n",child[i].weight);
    printf("Year of Birth:%d\n",child[i].year);
    printf("Parent names:%s\n",child[i].parent_names);
        
}
```

NOTE: you can't use `fflush` to flush the `stdin` stream as you can with the `stdout` stream, so you always have to be mindful of the `\n` that is left in stdin after a call to `scanf` as you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {

char name[50];
float weight;
int year;
char parent_names[50];
}newborn;

int main() {

int i;
newborn child[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    printf("\nWhat is the child's name?\n");
    scanf("%s",child[i].name);
    
    
    printf("What is the child's weight in Kg?\n");
    scanf("%f",&child[i].weight);
    
    
    printf("What is the child's year of birth?\n");
    scanf("%d",&child[i].year);
    
    
    printf("What are the names of the Mother and Father?\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(child[i].parent_names, sizeof child[i].parent_names, stdin);
    

    printf("Name:%s\n",child[i].name);
    printf("Weight:%f\n",child[i].weight);
    printf("Year of Birth:%d\n",child[i].year);
    printf("Parent names:%s\n",child[i].parent_names);
        
}
}
```